# Creating set functions union, difference, intersection in SML

Tags: functional-programming, set, sml, set-difference, set-union

I'm trying to write three function definitions that can be used to manipulate sets in SML. As you can see we are basing the implementation on lists.

Union is the set of all elements in both Set s and Set t. (No duplicates are allowed)

Intersection is the set in which the elements is a part of both Set s and Set t.

If Set s and Set t are sets, then the relative complement of Set s  in Set t, is the set of elements in Set t, but not in Set s.

Right now the code looks like this:

```
  fun filter p [] = []
 |       filter p (h::t) =
                 if p h
                 then h :: (filter p t)
                 else (filter p t);

  fun mem [] a = false
 |        mem (h::t) a = (a=h) orelse (mem t a);


 signature SETS =
       sig
                 type ''a set
                 val union : ''a set -> ''a set -> ''a set
                 val intersection : ''a set -> ''a set -> ''a set
                 val difference : ''a set -> ''a set -> ''a set
       end;

 structure Set : SETS =
       struct
                 type ''a set = ''a list;
                 fun union s t = **(Code goes here)**
                 fun intersection s t = **(Code goes here)**
                 fun difference s t =  **(Code goes here)**
       end;
```

As you can see there is two helpfunctions to be used when needed - mem and filter.filter will go through a list and only keep those elements that satisfy some
boolean function p, while mem just checks a list to see if it contains the value a.

Comment: What did you try? StackOverflow isn't really a marketplace for solving student homeworks.

Comment: Sorry -- what exactly is your question? Are you asking for someone to implement `union`, `intersection`, and `difference` for you?